# How to get records where no other record has specific value

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table named `Employee` as listed below

[image: Employee]

In this table i want to write such query which will give me such employee whose reference_type is not 1

```
Select * from Employee where Reference_Type <> 1
```

which will give me all possible values expect '1' but I need output as employee 2 because  ithis employee has no `Reference_Type` 1.

Comment: Your query will give you ((1,2,4),(1,3,3),(2,1,3),(2,2,4),(2,3,5),(3,2,2),(3,3,4)) for this part of the table. 

If this is incorrect, please elaborate what is the result you are willing to see. If this is not the result you get, please provide the result you get.

Comment: The query looks correct. In what way do you get incorrect data? Missing rows? rows with Reference_Type equal 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want all employees where no record has `Reference_Type` 1, use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM dbo.Employee e
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Employee e2
    WHERE e2.pk_employee_id = e.pk_employee_id 
    AND   e2.Reference_Type = 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from Employee where pk_employee_ID not in 
(select a.pk_employee_ID from Employee a where a. Reference_Type = 1)
```

Comment: This returns no employees since every employee has a Reference_Type <> 1.

Comment: Sorry, typo, it should be "Reference_Type=1"

Comment: this will return incorrect and unwanted data as you will get employee who does not have reference_type 1 but other 2 will be listed in the case i have posted example...